# Visual studio update behind a proxy server

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, proxy, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I'm using Visual studio 2015 inside our organization. I want to be able to use the Extensions and updates features but I always get a connection problem when I try to access the "online" or "update" section. We are behind a proxy server.
The problem is related to the configuration of the proxy because the feature work well if I connect my pc on a direct internet connection.
The proxy is managed by another organization and I don't know much about that subject.
I need help on what I should say so they understand what they need to change.
Does someone knows what configuration need to be put in place to make that VS feature works?
thanks

Comment: There might be something about the route is using. The update are using the http protocol (and also the news). The extensions are using the https(443) protocol. Visual studio seems to be using the IE proxy config file for the update but not for the 443. It's using a different route. maybe this is what is causing the problem. Is there a way to force Visual studio to use IE proxy config file (wpad file).

Comment: You should try adding the proxy configuration in your devenv.exe.config found in this path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE.
More info on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/dn771556.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're working on Windows, you can try to set the Proxy for VS in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">  
    <proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://proxy.bn.ch:8080" />
  </defaultProxy> 
</system.net>
```

This overrules the standard Proxy Settings from IE.

Answer (score 0):

the answer of tk78 is correct but if you are behind a company proxy probably you need to add user, password and domain on the proxy address like this:

```xml
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">  
    <proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://domain%5Cusername:password@youproxyaddress:portnumber" />
  </defaultProxy> 
</system.net>
```

The '%5C' is the escape for '' .

Comment: Or add the credentials to Windows Credential Manager.